# Clojure: convert array of maps into sequence of :key val

Tags: clojure

How to convert in Clojure a sequence with maps structure (:data), like this:

```
{:data ({2019-09-20 3.673202} {2018-01-01 4.673202} {2018-01-02 5.673202}) }
```

into a map of key-value pairs, like this one:

```
{:data {2019-09-20 3.673202, 2018-01-01 4.673202, 2018-01-02 5.673202}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is `into`:

```
(let [data [ map1 map2 map3 ...]
  (into {} data))
```

Comment: I chose this option because I find it more expressive, however @akond's answer is also good.

Answer (score 2):

```
(let [data '({"2019-09-20" 3.673202} {"2018-01-01" 4.673202} {"2018-01-02" 5.673202})]
    (apply merge data))
=> {"2019-09-20" 3.673202, "2018-01-01" 4.673202, "2018-01-02" 5.673202}
```